# How to change color of a input text field when you click on it using javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, onclick, background-color

I am new to JavaScript and I need some help with my project!

I am trying to create a form for a company website that allows visitors to email the company directly. When the user clicks the input type=text field to write in their name, I want the background to change color to indicate that they are in that field. Right now I have something like this:

`<input class="field" type="text"  id = "input" onclick="changeMe()" name="name" placeholder="Name" required autofocus/>`

`<script>`
`function changeMe() {
        document.getElementById("input").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }`
`</script>`

I know it is easier to do in jquery but unfortunately my teacher only wants us to use javascript right now and mine doesn't seem to be working. I want the background to change colour as soon as the user clicks the input field even before they start typing.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: I would suggest to create a `class` with `background-color: blue`, and add that `class` to `input` when you click on it. This code should work. You are making error somewhere else. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1p6r8zfj/)

Answer (score 0):

heres a sample code 
more help you can find on 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jG95a/

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>   
  This is a title
  </title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor()
    {
    alert("bla")
   document.getElementById("text1").style("backgroundColor":"red"); 
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input id="text1" type="text" onkeypress="changeColor()">
</form>


</body>

</html>
```